# UrlFetch with custom user-agent string?

Tags: google-apps-script, user-agent

Is it possible to change the user-agent string used with Google Apps Script `UrlFetchApp.fetch` requests?

[This discussion](http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/apps-script/ejLKdBKHK24/discussion) from 2010 insinuates that the UrlFetch module in Google Apps Script supports adding the `User-Agent` header to the optional `headers` collection, like the UrlFetch module of Google App Engine does. However, [the GAS documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_urlfetchapp) states nothing about this. A test script I made also shows it doesn't work.

Test script:

```
function testUserAgentString(){
  var page;
  try {
    page = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.myuseragent.net/',
        {headers: {"User-Agent":
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"
        }}).getContentText();
    Logger.log(page);
  } catch(_) {}
}
```

Log output (minus irrelevant HTML) was:

`Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; GoogleDocs; script; +http://docs.google.com)`

which is the default user-agent string used when doing UrlFetch requests by GAS.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

**Edit:** As this is currently not possible, I placed an enhancement [request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2544) on the Issue Tracker, per Arun's suggestion.

Comment: You're not missing anything - Apps Script uses its own user-agent header for outgoing requests. 

Is there any reason for changing it?

Comment: Yes. Various websites change their content and layout based on the user-agent string used. A website I want to fetch, provides HTML5 videos when requested with a Safari IOS user-agent string and a proprietary SilverLight video player when the default GAS UA string is used.

Comment: My guess is that they just don't want to enable setting this header.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not possible today. Please log an enhancement request on the [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/) with your use cases so this can be reviewed and considered.

Comment: It is still impossibe in 2019

Comment: Is it possible now?

Comment: And How about now?

Comment: It is not possible as of today. And I guess it is done on purpose. I supposed they don't want to be used as a free crawling platform.

Comment: Not possible as of today - 2024-03-06 - I tried different combinations, but, no avail.

Answer (score -1):

You can send header information with UrlFetchApp in this way:

```
var url = "http://mymagentohost/api/rest/products?limit=2"

var params = { 
  headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/json", 'Accept': "application/json",
             'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'},
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
  method: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json",
  validateHttpsCertificates: false,
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
```

Just add the user agent information in the headers section. Hope it helps!

Credit goes out to: [Aditya Advani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094020/1499769)

Comment: As you can see in the code I posted in the question, I also hoped this would work. But for me it didn't! Have you found it to be working currently?

Comment: I tried this function in my code yesterday and it worked like a charm! Give it a try and let me know. :)

Comment: OP is specifically asking about setting the `User-Agent` header.  Your answer doesn't address this.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewLeingang for pointing that out! I forgot to add the most important part. I tweaked the code accordingly. With this in mind, please reconsider your downvote. Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you verify that it works? [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56100109/297797) suggests that UrlFetchApp doesn't allow changing this header.  I just ran the code in that answer and got the same results.

Comment: It does work, I use it in my code. Give it a try! :)

Comment: It “works” in that it runs without any warning or error, but it silently fails to do what you want.  I took your code and replaced `url` with [`https://manytools.org/http-html-text/user-agent-string/`](https://manytools.org/http-html-text/user-agent-string/).  I parsed the response (it's in the `<code>` block on the returned page) and logged it.  I got: `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; ...`.  That agrees with the other answer I found.  I assume this is to prevent script authors from circumventing `robots.txt` security measures.

Comment: Do you know an alternative ?