# Does UrlFetchApp support User Agent header?

Tags: google-apps-script, http-headers, user-agent

I try to use the following code to get mobile version of the site:

```
var headers = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8H7 Safari/6533.18.5"
};
var options = {
  "method": "get",
  "headers": headers
};

response  = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

But standard desktop version of the site is returned. Doesn't [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)) support User Agent header?

Comment: Looks like it is not supported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067462/urlfetch-with-custom-user-agent-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UrlFetch with custom user-agent string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067462/urlfetch-with-custom-user-agent-string)